# Excel VBA click issues

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have Excel VBA code that opens MS Access Database and filters based on Cell Value in the excel file cells.  I have a defined range but access will open if I click anywhere in excel (Note only correctly filters if I click correct cells thought).

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Init As Integer
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim LPath As String


   'Path to Access database
    LPath = "J:\Admin\Access Database for Punch List.accdb"

     'Exit if selection is more than one cell
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Validate if selected cell is in range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A23:A2000"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then



        ' Assign studentid value from current cell
        Init = Target.Value


        ' Call the open procedure with current cell value

        Call CheckIfFileOpen

    End If
 Call OpenAccess(Init)
End Sub

Sub CheckIfFileOpen()

Dim fileName As String
Dim oApp As Object
Dim Init As Integer


fileName = "J:\Admin\Access Database for Punch List.accdb"

'Call function to check if the file is open
If IsFileOpen(fileName) = False Then



Else

    'The file is open or another error occurred
    With GetObject(, "access.application").Quit
End With

End If


End Sub

Sub OpenAccess(Init)


    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim LPath As String




    'Path to Access database
    LPath = "J:\Kyle\Access Database for Punch List.accdb"

       'Open Access and make visible
   Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oApp.Visible = True


   'Open Access database as defined by LPath variable

     oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase LPath
   oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_AllRecords"
   oApp.DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "Initiative_Nbr=" & Init
    oApp.Forms("frm_AllRecords").SetFocus


End Sub
```

Outcome would be code to only have the VBA run when I click on a cell in my range.

Comment: `Call OpenAccess(Init)` is outside of your logical check where you "Validate if selected cell is in range". Put that call *inside* the `If` block.

Comment: ^ literally exactly what I was about to type. You have an order of operations problem.

Comment: Thank you, yes it works Great!

Comment: Proper indentation of your code would make it easier for you to identify such issues.

Comment: Lee Mac thank you but how code looks here does not always equate to how it looks in VBA environment.